# Apache Lucene: Is Relevance Score Always Between 0 and 1?

Tags: apache, lucene, relevance

Greetings,

I have the following Apache Lucene snippet that's giving me some nice results:

```
int numHits=100;
        int resultsPerPage=100;
        IndexSearcher searcher=new IndexSearcher(reader);
        TopScoreDocCollector collector=TopScoreDocCollector.create(numHits,true);
        Query q=parser.parse(queryString);
        searcher.search(q,collector);
        ScoreDoc[] hits=collector.topDocs(0*resultsPerPage,resultsPerPage).scoreDocs;

        Results r=new Results();
        r.length=hits.length;
        for(int i=0;i<hits.length;i++){
            Document doc=searcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
            double distanceKm=getGreatCircleDistance(lucene2double(doc.get("lat")), lucene2double(doc.get("lng")), Double.parseDouble(userLat), Double.parseDouble(userLng));
            double newRelevance=((1/distanceKm)*Math.log(hits[i].score)/Math.log(2))*(0-1);
            System.out.println(hits[i].doc+"\t"+hits[i].score+"\t"+doc.get("content")+"\t"+"Km="+distanceKm+"\trlvnc="+String.valueOf(newRelevance));
        }
```

What I want to know, is hits[i].score always between 0 and 1? It seems that way, but I can't be sure. I've even checked the Lucene documentation (class ScoreDocs) to no avail. You'll see I'm calculating the log of the "newRelevance" value, which is based on hits[i].score. I need hits[i].score to be between 0 and 1, because if it is below zero, I'll get an error; above 1 and the sign will change from negative to positive.

I hope some Lucene expert out there can offer me some insight.

Many thanks,

Comment: FWIW, [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) is always in [0,1]. Lucene uses a modified form of this, which may deviate in complex ways from the theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scores are between 1 and 0, but the top score does not have to be 1.
Scores are always relative to one another, and a direct comparison should not really be made between scores of two different queries.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Yes, the score will always be between 0 and 1.</strike>

When Lucene calculates the score, it finds individual scores for term hits within fields, etc... and totals them. If the highest ranked hit has a total greater than 1, all of the document scores are normalised to be between 0 and 1, with the highest ranked document having a score of 1. If however no document's total was greater than 1, no normalisation occurs and the scores are returned as-is. This is why sometimes the top document has a score of 1 and other times has a score lower than 1.

---

**EDIT:** Having done a bit more research, **the answer is most likely no**. In the version of Lucene I am familiar with (v2.3.2), searches pass through the `Hits` object, whose `GetMoreDocs()` method normalises scores if any of them are greater than 1. In later versions, it appears to be that this is not the case as the `Hits` class is no longer used. Whether your scores will be between 0 and 1 will depend on which version of Lucene you are using, and which mechanism is being used to search.

To quote from the [Lucene mailing list](http://lucene.markmail.org/search/?q=score%20range#query%3ascore%20range+page:1+mid%3ajc57otnsvyuvvlrx+state%3aresults):

> The score is an arbitrary number > 0. It's not normalized to anything, it should
>   only be used to e.g. sort the results

Comment: I'm using Lucene 2.9.2. I hope it's between 0 and 1. If the relevance can go over 1, I'll have to look at using something other than logarithms.

Comment: Here's a hopefully better link to the same mailing thread: http://www.lucidimagination.com/search/document/ea3f9d1167fce259/range_score_in_lucene#3969a7cd3b7b7681 . Basically, you are trying to combine the distance with the score, which is a tough problem. I guess you can try custom sorting with some weights and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Lucene scores are always normalised, i.e. the top-scoring hits get `1` (or near to it). The values should then always be between `0` and `1`.  By extension, this means that the scores have no objective meaning, i.e. they cannot be compared with anything other than other hits from the same result set.

Disclaimer: I am not a Lucene Scientist. This is based only on my observations of Lucene in action, though, I've never seen this actually documented, so I may have got completely the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what I thought. I'd like to firm it up with something official though... This is a critical part of my app!